# Decrement a database table value if value >= 1 else... Delete the record

Tags: php, sql, delete-row

I want to decrement a database table value if the field value is greater than or equal to 1 (`>= 1`). Otherwise (if it IS less than 1) then I want to delete that whole database record, My code decrements the value continuously but does not delete the record when it reaches less than 1.

I think the `$Check` variable does not hold the `Quantity` field value but I'm not sure:

Using MySQL

Here is my code:

```
$Check = "SELECT Quantity FROM Cart WHERE ItemCode = '1'";

if($Check >= '1')
{
    $Query = "UPDATE Cart SET Quantity = Quantity - 1 WHERE ItemCode = '1'";
    mysql_query($Query);
}
else
{
    $DeleteRow = "DELETE FROM Cart WHERE ItemCode = '1'";   
    mysql_query($DeleteRow);
}

mysql_close();
```

Comment: microsoft sql server, mysql, oracle or postgresql?

Comment: MySQL sorry have just amended the post!

Comment: The string "SELECT Quantity FROM Cart WHERE ItemCode = '1'" is always >= to the integer 1. You need to run the query

Comment: Yes, that's the whole point, so whenever this php file is called it will do the above, so it will keep reducing the `Quantity` value by 1 each time it is called, meaning it will eventually get to < 1

Comment: You need to run the query! $Check contains some SQL not the result of it will produce.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this piece of code:

```
<?php

    $Check = "SELECT Quantity FROM Cart WHERE ItemCode = '1'";
    $result = mysql_query($Check);

    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    if($row['Quantity'] >= '1'){
    $Query = "UPDATE Cart SET Quantity = ".$row['Quantity']." - 1 WHERE ItemCode = '1'";

    mysql_query($Query);

    }
    else
    {
    $DeleteRow = "DELETE FROM Cart WHERE ItemCode = '1'";
    mysql_query($DeleteRow);
    }

    mysql_close();
```

?>

When you have this code running ok, try to adapting it to the mysqli extension on the procedural way; the mysql extension is deprecated.

It's not recommended the use of the mysql extension; you should try mysqli or PDO instead, follow this link and made your choice: http://www.phptherightway.com/#databases

Answer (score 0):

You're never actually *running* the query to get the record count, you're simply storing the query string itself into the `$Count` variable. That's why it's continuously decrementing the count.

You could run the query and then extract the quantity column (the return value of running the query is a result set, you still need to extract the column value) but that also has problems, specifically that the data may change between the check and the update/deletion (known as a race condition).

The best thing to do here, from a database point of view, is to start a transaction to ensure the whole thing is atomic. Within the transaction, you would have:

```
update cart set quantity = quantity - 1 where itemcode = '1'
delete from cart where quantity < 1 and itemcode = '1'
```

This guarantees the operation does exactly what you need without the possibility of a race condition.

Comment: Why this is not working for me?  I receive a sql syntax error...UPDATE cart SET qty=qty-1 WHERE id='1'
DELETE FROM cart WHERE qty<1 AND id='1'

Comment: @tziuka, no idea. Your best bet would be to post an actual *question* with the error message you're getting as well. That way (1) a lot more people will see it; and (2) We won't have to guess what the error is.

Comment: Thank you, but I tryed it in mysql, and it gives me sintax error, if I run one instruction at time it works fine, but both not, so I made 2 statements and run them one after the other, And it works good. Have a good day!

Comment: @tziuka, it was meant to be two statements, that's why they're on separate lines. What I meant by running them as a single transaction was to wrap them with something like `start transaction` and `commit`.

Comment: :)) ooo... I thought that is one statement and I tried it directly in phpmyadmin, sql section, with one query ...